Force gdal.warp to ignore source file no data-values
I am trying to crop a satellite image (in GeoTIFF format) to the extent of a region of interest (irregularly shaped polygon outlining the area of a glacier) using gdal.warp in Python. While doing this I want to keep the value of the no data-pixels in the original image (in this case 0), and assign a different no data-value to the pixels that are being cut off by the polygon, so that I end up with a final image that includes two kinds of no data-pixels: one for "true" no data in the region of interest and one for no data as a result of cropping the image - basically just the fill values that are being created by gdal.warp.
This what my code looks like:
img_crop = gdal.Warp(img_out, img_in,
                     cutlineDSName=mask,
                     cropToCutline=True, 
                     dstNodata=np.nan)

gdal.warp now recognizes that the pixels with value 0 in the input image are no data-values and automatically sets them to np.nan, but I would like it keep them as 0. I have tried to set srcNodata=np.nan in the hope that it might cause gdal.warp to "forget" that 0 is a no data-value of the input image, but it doesn't seem to work.

Have a look at gdal_edit.py with -unsetnodata option https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html
